# Adding list of list except last list

Tags: python

If I have a matrix

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

How do I loop over to sum all of the entries except the last list? That is stop the for loop before the final list.

In this case, the output should be 21 `(=1+2+3+4+5+6)`.

Answer (score 2):

One way using list comprehension and slicing:

```
sum([sum(i) for i in a[:-1]])
```

or as a generator and slicing as idjaw mentions:

```
sum(sum(i) in for i in a[:-1])
```

Output:

```
21
```

Comment: I was under the impression the generator would be faster, but my time comparison is showing that `sum(map(sum, d[:-1]))` is actually outperforming the generator approach. Just for the fun of providing a micro-optimized solution just because it's fun. :P